# How to call any method in the WCF webservice asynchronously from the viewmodel of a MVVM design pattern?

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, asynchronous

I am new to silverlight.
In my office project I have seen an asynchronous call is made to a method of Web service and the eventargs passed on is of type **methodNameCompletedEventArgs**.
I want to know the basics of such asynchronous calls and how to make a detailed syntax of such asynchronous calls in C# ViewModel.

Can anyone help me guide through.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to generate your proxy using [SlsVcUtil.EXE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197958%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) then you can simply  bind  your method which  will be asynchronous  by default in silvelight to your ViewModel
here an example ofhow you can  generate  your client proxy

```
slsvcutil http://example.com/service.svc?wsdl /edb /namespace:"*,SilverlightApplication1.ServiceReference1" /ct:System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1 /r:"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.#####\System.Windows.dll"
```

you can  download a getting started example from [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/Getting-Started-WCF-RIA-1469cbe2)